# Upgrade Antelope to Barracuda on Slave

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.6, master-slave-replication, antelope

I received a `Last_Errno: 1118`,

> Last_Error: Error 'Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.' on query.

I then compared my master and slave and have found the `innodb_file_format` and `innodb_file_format_max` on my master are `barracuda` but `antelope` on my slaves.

I think the barracuda increase noted here, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-file-format.html, explains this:

> index key prefixes up to 3072 bytes

explains the issue so now how can I safely upgrade the file format of my slaves?

Master:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.41-84.1, for Linux (x86_64) using  6.2
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
5.6.41-84.1-log
```

Slave:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.41-84.1, for Linux (x86_64) using  6.2
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
5.6.41-84.1
```

Slave2:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.41-84.1, for Linux (x86_64) using  6.2
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
5.6.41-84.1
```

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tags` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `Details` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UserID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateAdded` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Excerpt` text,
  `Disclosures` varchar(10000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Discussion` text,
  `Acknowledgements` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TextContent` mediumtext,
  `Materials` text,
  `HTMLTopContent` text,
  `StreamID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DatePublished` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Access` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DurationMonths` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DurationDays` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AuthorProduced` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CollaborationType` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Indexed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Revision` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Results` text,
  `Stage` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SectionID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `xmlcache` text,
  `MaterialMigration` text,
  `keycat` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `doi` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pmid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Issue` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Introduction` text,
  `Citations` text,
  `SID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Title` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `AbbreviatedTitle` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Article` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `IsInPress` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `FinalizedDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `ProgressStep` int(2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT,
  `DraftPublished` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `Articles_StreamID_Active_DatePublished` (`StreamID`,`Active`,`DatePublished`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `AbstractTest` (`Details`,`Name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `xmlcache` (`xmlcache`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `articles_fulltext` (`Name`,`Tags`,`Details`,`Excerpt`,`Disclosures`,`Introduction`,`Acknowledgements`,`TextContent`,`Discussion`,`HTMLTopContent`,`Rep_Results`,`Citations`,`xmlcache`,`Materials`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `xmlcache_2` (`xmlcache`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Materials` (`Materials`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED |
```

Post slave update:

```
+-------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name                             | Value                  |
+-------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| ignore_builtin_innodb                     | OFF                    |
| innodb_adaptive_flushing                  | ON                     |
| innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm              | 10                     |
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index                | ON                     |
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index_partitions     | 1                      |
| innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay           | 150000                 |
| innodb_additional_mem_pool_size           | 8388608                |
| innodb_api_bk_commit_interval             | 5                      |
| innodb_api_disable_rowlock                | OFF                    |
| innodb_api_enable_binlog                  | OFF                    |
| innodb_api_enable_mdl                     | OFF                    |
| innodb_api_trx_level                      | 0                      |
| innodb_autoextend_increment               | 64                     |
| innodb_autoinc_lock_mode                  | 1                      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown       | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now               | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_filename               | ib_buffer_pool         |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances              | 8                      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort             | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup        | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_now               | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_populate               | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size                   | 2147483648             |
| innodb_change_buffer_max_size             | 25                     |
| innodb_change_buffering                   | all                    |
| innodb_checksum_algorithm                 | innodb                 |
| innodb_checksums                          | ON                     |
| innodb_cleaner_lsn_age_factor             | high_checkpoint        |
| innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled              | OFF                    |
| innodb_commit_concurrency                 | 0                      |
| innodb_compressed_columns_threshold       | 96                     |
| innodb_compressed_columns_zip_level       | 6                      |
| innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct  | 5                      |
| innodb_compression_level                  | 6                      |
| innodb_compression_pad_pct_max            | 50                     |
| innodb_concurrency_tickets                | 5000                   |
| innodb_corrupt_table_action               | assert                 |
| innodb_data_file_path                     | ibdata1:12M:autoextend |
| innodb_data_home_dir                      |                        |
| innodb_disable_sort_file_cache            | OFF                    |
| innodb_doublewrite                        | ON                     |
| innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm          | backoff                |
| innodb_fake_changes                       | OFF                    |
| innodb_fast_shutdown                      | 1                      |
| innodb_file_format                        | Barracuda              |
| innodb_file_format_check                  | ON                     |
| innodb_file_format_max                    | Barracuda              |
| innodb_file_per_table                     | ON                     |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout               | 1                      |
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit            | 1                      |
| innodb_flush_method                       |                        |
| innodb_flush_neighbors                    | 1                      |
| innodb_flushing_avg_loops                 | 30                     |
| innodb_force_load_corrupted               | OFF                    |
| innodb_force_recovery                     | 0                      |
| innodb_foreground_preflush                | exponential_backoff    |
| innodb_ft_aux_table                       |                        |
| innodb_ft_cache_size                      | 8000000                |
| innodb_ft_enable_diag_print               | OFF                    |
| innodb_ft_enable_stopword                 | ON                     |
| innodb_ft_max_token_size                  | 84                     |
| innodb_ft_min_token_size                  | 3                      |
| innodb_ft_num_word_optimize               | 2000                   |
| innodb_ft_result_cache_limit              | 2000000000             |
| innodb_ft_server_stopword_table           |                        |
| innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree                 | 2                      |
| innodb_ft_total_cache_size                | 640000000              |
| innodb_ft_user_stopword_table             |                        |
| innodb_io_capacity                        | 200                    |
| innodb_io_capacity_max                    | 2000                   |
| innodb_kill_idle_transaction              | 0                      |
| innodb_large_prefix                       | ON                     |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout                  | 50                     |
| innodb_locking_fake_changes               | ON                     |
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog            | OFF                    |
| innodb_log_arch_dir                       | ./                     |
| innodb_log_arch_expire_sec                | 0                      |
| innodb_log_archive                        | OFF                    |
| innodb_log_block_size                     | 512                    |
| innodb_log_buffer_size                    | 8388608                |
| innodb_log_checksum_algorithm             | innodb                 |
| innodb_log_compressed_pages               | ON                     |
| innodb_log_file_size                      | 50331648               |
| innodb_log_files_in_group                 | 2                      |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir                 | ./                     |
| innodb_lru_scan_depth                     | 1024                   |
| innodb_max_bitmap_file_size               | 104857600              |
| innodb_max_changed_pages                  | 1000000                |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct                | 75                     |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm            | 0                      |
| innodb_max_purge_lag                      | 0                      |
| innodb_max_purge_lag_delay                | 0                      |
| innodb_mirrored_log_groups                | 1                      |
| innodb_monitor_disable                    |                        |
| innodb_monitor_enable                     |                        |
| innodb_monitor_reset                      |                        |
| innodb_monitor_reset_all                  |                        |
| innodb_numa_interleave                    | OFF                    |
| innodb_old_blocks_pct                     | 37                     |
| innodb_old_blocks_time                    | 1000                   |
| innodb_online_alter_log_max_size          | 134217728              |
| innodb_open_files                         | 2000                   |
| innodb_optimize_fulltext_only             | OFF                    |
| innodb_page_size                          | 16384                  |
| innodb_print_all_deadlocks                | OFF                    |
| innodb_print_lock_wait_timeout_info       | OFF                    |
| innodb_purge_batch_size                   | 300                    |
| innodb_purge_threads                      | 1                      |
| innodb_random_read_ahead                  | OFF                    |
| innodb_read_ahead_threshold               | 56                     |
| innodb_read_io_threads                    | 4                      |
| innodb_read_only                          | OFF                    |
| innodb_replication_delay                  | 0                      |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout                | OFF                    |
| innodb_rollback_segments                  | 128                    |
| innodb_sched_priority_cleaner             | 19                     |
| innodb_show_locks_held                    | 10                     |
| innodb_show_verbose_locks                 | 0                      |
| innodb_sort_buffer_size                   | 1048576                |
| innodb_spin_wait_delay                    | 6                      |
| innodb_stats_auto_recalc                  | ON                     |
| innodb_stats_include_delete_marked        | OFF                    |
| innodb_stats_method                       | nulls_equal            |
| innodb_stats_on_metadata                  | OFF                    |
| innodb_stats_persistent                   | ON                     |
| innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages      | 20                     |
| innodb_stats_sample_pages                 | 8                      |
| innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages       | 8                      |
| innodb_status_output                      | OFF                    |
| innodb_status_output_locks                | OFF                    |
| innodb_strict_mode                        | OFF                    |
| innodb_support_xa                         | ON                     |
| innodb_sync_array_size                    | 1                      |
| innodb_sync_spin_loops                    | 30                     |
| innodb_table_locks                        | ON                     |
| innodb_thread_concurrency                 | 0                      |
| innodb_thread_sleep_delay                 | 10000                  |
| innodb_tmpdir                             |                        |
| innodb_track_changed_pages                | OFF                    |
| innodb_undo_directory                     | .                      |
| innodb_undo_logs                          | 128                    |
| innodb_undo_tablespaces                   | 0                      |
| innodb_use_atomic_writes                  | OFF                    |
| innodb_use_global_flush_log_at_trx_commit | ON                     |
| innodb_use_native_aio                     | ON                     |
| innodb_use_sys_malloc                     | ON                     |
| innodb_version                            | 5.6.41-84.1            |
| innodb_write_io_threads                   | 4                      |
+-------------------------------------------+------------------------+
148 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What versions are involved?  It sounds like you have a newer Master and an older Slave.  Also, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table involved.

Comment: @RickJames I've added the output of `mysql --version` and the last line from the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statement. If there is an additional line(s) needed please let me know. There are 85 columns and 8 indexes in place so I thought that'd be too much to add. 1 `PRIMARY KEY`, 2 `KEY`, and 5 `FULLTEXT KEY`

Comment: Looking at all `innodb` variables I notice the following differ, `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, `innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm`, `innodb_file_format` (as previously noted), `innodb_file_format_max` (PN), `innodb_ft_cache_size`, `innodb_ft_min_token_size`, and `innodb_status_output`.

Comment: `Distrib 5.6.41-84.1` refers to the command line `mysql`.  Need to know the server:  `SELECT @@version;`

Comment: I think we need all of `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Notice how the error message suggests changing some datatypes.  If you have a lot of `VARCHAR(255)`, _perhaps_ shrinking some of them to reasonable sizes would solve the problem.

Comment: Drop the redundant fulltext index on `xmlcache`.

Comment: Where is `ProductID`?

Comment: @RickJames Oh, sorry, that's ID. Figured it'd be easier with normalized(ish) column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply changing to Barracuda is not sufficient to achieve much.

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format=Barracuda;
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table=1;
SET GLOBAL innodb_large_prefix=1;
logout & login (to get the global values);
ALTER TABLE tbl ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;  -- (or COMPRESSED)
```

More discussion on the 767 limit, plus workarounds:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes

Notice how the error message suggests changing some datatypes. If you have a lot of VARCHAR(255), perhaps shrinking some of them to reasonable sizes would solve the problem.

Have you changed `innodb_page_size`?  (You probably should not.)

Use `SELECT @@version;` to get the version of the *server*.  (`mysql --version` gets the version of that client.)

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be about 70% of RAM on each server -- if you have over 4GB of RAM.  If you have less, well, how tiny is your RAM?

The `SETs` above can be done temporarily (as shown) or permanently `my.cnf`.  In general, `1` == `ON` and `0` == `OFF` for any 2-value settings.

Hmmm...  Only the PK and a 3-column `KEY` come under the issue of 3072 (or 767), and neither of them seems to be more than 767.  So, I don't understand the Slave's complaint.  Fulltext does not have 767/3072 issues.

You have about 18 'large' text/blob columns.  With `ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT`, each would take up to 768+20 bytes before overlowing.  That's about 14KB, which is more than the 8KB limit.  Dynamic and Compressed take only 20 bytes each, so there is plenty of room.

An alternative to changing the row_format is to use 'vertical partitioning'.  That is, make a parallel table (same PK) and move some of the text columns into it.  (With a single extra table, you probably need to move 9 of them.)

**Short Answer**:  The Master and Slave had different `ROW_FORMATs`.

Comment: My current settings are for `innodb_large_prefix` = `OFF` and `innodb_file_per_table` = `ON`; both values should be `1` in `my.cnf`? Also the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is `2147483648` on master but only `134217728` on the slave. Is that an issue?

Comment: I haven't touched `innodb_page_size`.  My master has 2 more MBs than my slaves. `Slave 1 and 2: 31370 MB`, `Master: 31372 MB`

Comment: I added a few paragraphs to my Answer.  As for 31GB of RAM -- you could (should) increase the buffer_pool_size to, say, 20G on all machines.  I don't think it is part of the issue, however Compressed needs to keep both compressed and uncompressed blocks in the buffer_pool.

Comment: I've made the changes on slave 2 but the behavior persists. I've added all variables like `innodb` to the question. I used `show variables like '%innodb%';`.

Comment: @user3783243 - Please provide `SELECT * FROM information_schema.INNODB_SYS_TABLES WHERE name like '%test_table';`

Comment: Oh, thanks. That showed me the issue. I forgot the `ALTER TABLE tbl ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;` (I did compressed). After that works as expected. Thank you.

Comment: @user3783243 - Sorry; the row_format was an afterthought.  And I had to look up how to find it.  Are you saying that it was Barracuda+Compressed?  But it got 'better' with Barracuda+Dynamic?  Or that the Master and Slave had different Row_formats?

Comment: Yes, slave and master had different row formats. Slave have `antelope` and `compact`.

Answer (score 0):

After setting `innodb_file_format` on the slave, `ALTER TABLE {db}.{tbl} FORCE` for all innodb tables will re-create these as baracuda. Then `START SLAVE` again.